# Как изменить фон для ссылки?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Здравствуйте!

Нужно при нажатии на ссылку сделать ее активной, подкрасить фон. Делаю так

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.j-links').click(function () {
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

В css вот что

```
.links .j-links.active {
    background-color: orange;
    color: #2f8bd8;
}
```

На самой странице

```
<div class="links">
<a class="j-links" href="report.php"> Отчет </a>
<a class="j-links" href="statistics.php"> Статистика </a>
</div>
```

Это решение не работает..

Изменила ссылки на параграфы p - класс  active  навешивается..но нужен и переход по адресу..а для этого нужны ссылки..(

Comment: Смените тег на javascript, javascript - это не java ;) а то вам никто не ответит из целевой аудитории.

Comment: @Анна, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Comment: Вопрос в чем? Или вы похвастались своим решением?))

Comment: что не работает это решение..

Comment: так работает же))

Comment: [вот ваш код на jsfiddle][1]


  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/X87jX/1/

Comment: нет..без ссылок работает..если сделать параграфы..но это уже не то

Comment: все верно, кликнули по ссылке - покрасили ее на текущей странице и сразу перешли на другую. решение работает, а вот как обрабатывать и красить на следующей странице - это уже другой вопрос...

Comment: и вообще вам было бы неплохо позакрывать все свои текущие вопросы, которых за последние 2 дня насобиралось немало...

Comment: В том виде, как вы описываете, прекрасно [работает](http://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/caCvX/). ВОзможно, что-то конфликтует с другими частями скрипта или стилей. Посмотрите подробно, что происходит с помощью FireBug или похожего инструмента.

Answer (score 4):

По ссылке осуществляется переход, загружается новая страница? Раз так, нужно использовать псевдокласс `active`. Замените Ваш CSS на следующий:

```
.links a.j-links:active {
    background-color: orange;
    color: #2f8bd8;
}
```

P.S. «и уберите скрипт)» — [[@Gautama](/users/955/gautama-buddha)](/users/955/gautama-buddha)-Buddha

Comment: и уберите скрипт)

Answer (score 2):

В таком виде ничего не будет работать...страница же обновляется...если бы вы так подгружали что-то без перезагрузки то работало бы...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.j-links').click(function () {
        $(this).addClass('active');
        return false;
    });
});
```

будет менять но перехода на др страницу не будет